# Boolean mesh subtraction in SceneKit

Tags: swift, scenekit

I trying to figure out if there is a Boolean subtraction native in SceneKit. 
Simple operation like cutting a hole in a box from a sphere.

If not, are there any libraries (free) that I can look into?

My google search returned almost nothing for this topic.

Thank you

Comment: If you feel the question needs downvoting please explain why? This a legitimate question and Apple documentation does not have any information.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: The problem is that (based on the answer below) there is no native SceneKit operation for Boolean subtraction. I have tried to search for an answer to my issue to no avail. The community of possible can help me out.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find ... are off topic. End of story.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is it possible that you could pm or suggest a library instead of a comment here, since it is not allowed? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

At the moment SceneKit doesn’t have boolean operations built-in, operations also known as `Computational Binary Solid Geometry` (like mesh `subtraction` or mesh `unify`).

If you need such an op you will need to build your own op. But it's not easy.

Use `Model I/O` for getting solid voxelized models, so you can perform Constructive Solid Geometry Boolean operations on them in order to create a slew of more interesting and complex models.

Watch a WWDC 2017 video: [From Art to Engine with Model I/O](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/610/).

Look [here](http://asciiwwdc.com/2015/sessions/602) for boolean op info.

Comment: Thank you. You don’t happen to know of any libraries, do you? I really wouldn’t want to build my own right now